# How can i make Containers in Bootstrap side by side?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is my container. I think it looks really good, but it only shows one container on the right side, and I want it to show 3 side by side. How can I do this?
If I just copy and paste the code right beneath itself, the second container is underneath the first one.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>Product 2</h2>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sx" type="button">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap Grid!

To arrange any elements into a grid, use the Bootstrap grid system. Give the parent element the `row` class, and give any children the `col` class. This will make all the children elements share the parent horizontally.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>Product 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sx" type="button">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could replace `col` with `col-4`, which would do almost the same thing, but would be more explicit.

You could add a breakpoint (like `sm`) to the class (so `col-sm`), to make it automatically wrap vertically when you resize the window to a certain breakpoint.

Learn all about the Bootstrap grid system [here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h
You try it:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       <h2>Product 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sx" type="button">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`
don't forget : 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```